# Determine NLS_LANG on linux

Tags: linux, oracle, utf-8, character-encoding

How do I determine the NLS_LANG setting for my Oracle Client on linux?

I haven't set the NLS_LANG explicitly.

Is it necessary to set and export the variable NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 for applications delivering utf-8 encoded characters to the database?

Is the Oracle client already aware of the encoding based on my locale?

```
me@ora11gR2> !echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8


me@ora11gR2> !locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

me@ora11gR2> !echo $NLS_LANG


me@ora11gR2> @.[$NLS_LANG]
SP2-0310: unable to open file ".[$NLS_LANG]"
```

Comment: The first echo you're doing is giving you the NLS_LANG setting for your client... what's the problem with this?

Comment: @Ben Does my Oracle Client translate the en_US.UTF-8 into NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8? Why can't I read this value from within sqlplus?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, so I thought I'd share an old answer from the old days that still works from SQL*Plus.

```
@%NLS_LANG%
```

this outputs something like:

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "ENGLISH_IRELAND.UTF8"
```

Which tells you that the NLS_LANG environment variable is set to `ENGLISH_IRELAND.UTF8`

Alternatively you can run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_charset FROM v$session_connect_info
WHERE sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
```

which outputs:

```
CLIENT_CHARSET
--------------------
UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some confusion here.  The characterset used in the database can be seen in `V$NLS_PARAMETER`.  In order for the client, i.e. the terminal program that SQL*Plus is running in, to correctly display the characters queried from the database, either the client characterset must match the database characterset, or before running SQL*Plus, set NLS_LANG to the characterset of the terminal program.  Then SQL*Plus will automatically translate/convert the characterset for correct display in the terminal.

So, what characterset does the terminal program use?  Set the NLS_LANG parameter accordingly before running SQL*Plus.